# python regExp search with lookarounds

Tags: python, regex

In my test program I get an input that goes like

```
str = "TestID277RStep01CtrAx-mn00112345"
```

Here, I want to use regExp to form groups that return me the following

```
str = "Test(ID277)(R)(Step01)(CtrAx-mn001)12345"
```

My goal is to end up with 4 vars

```
var1 = "ID277"
var2 = "R"
var3 = "Step01"
var4 = "CtrAx-mn001"
```

I have so far tried

```
regx = ".*Test(ID[0-9]+)([RP]?)(Step(?=\d)\d+)?(Ctr(?=[A-Z][a-z]-/d{3}))?.*"
re_testInp = re.compile ( regx, re.IGNORECASE )
srch = re_testInp.search( r'^' + str )
print srch.groups()
```

I seem to be getting the first 3 groups right but unable to get the last one.
Almost close to pulling all my hair out with this one. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you get `CtrAx-mn001` from `...ReqAx-mn001...`? Also, what is `|var 1||var2||var3||var4|`?

Comment: Tx @PhuNgo for pointing out. Apologies "Req" was a typo ( That is another variation that I expect to be able to handle once this is solved ). Elaborated on what I meant by var1, 2...

Comment: What's the purpose of the `(?=)` lookaheads?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me fine with Python3.6.0 and the following pattern:

```
.*Test(ID[0-9]+)([RP]?)(Step(?=\d)\d+)?(.*\-(?=[A-Za-z][a-z]\d{3})[A-Za-z][a-z]\d{3})?.*
```

I only changed the last capturing group as I'll explain what was wrong, in my opinion, with the pattern you included:

.*Test(ID[0-9]+)([RP]?)(Step(?=\d)\d+)?**(Ctr(?=[A-Z][a-z]/d{3}))**?.*

Do notice that the capture group in bold will not find a match because:

1. You attempt to match a literal 'Ctr', also you did not consider the literal '-'. I do not know what is the possible text you try to match there exactly but I generalized it to: **.*-**
2. You wrote **/d{3}** instead of **\d{3}**
3. In the test string you included: '...ReqAx-**m**n...' the m is lower cased. You should change the pattern to: (Ctr(?=**[A-Za-z]**[a-z]/d{3})) if you want to support lowercase as well.
4. You do not use the lookahead assertion properly. As stated in: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

   > (?=...)
   >
   > Matches if ... matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the string.
   >   This is called a lookahead assertion. For example, Isaac (?=Asimov)
   >   will match 'Isaac ' only if it’s followed by 'Asimov'.

   Meaning you should change the capturing group to: **(.*-(?=[A-Za-z][a-z]\d{3})[A-Za-z][a-z]\d{3})**

In: **(Step(?=\d)\d+)** I assume you thought the first digit would be captured in the lookahead assertion, but both digits are captured by the following **\d+**

Ben.

Comment: How is `(?=[A-Za-z][a-z]\d{3})[A-Za-z][a-z]\d{3}` different from just `[A-Za-z][a-z]\d{3}`?

Comment: There is an extra '?' at the end meaning this whole group is optional, perhaps OP intends to disqualify a match without continuing evaluating the rest of the string.

He encloses the entire pattern within: .\* and .\*

Comment: Thanks a lot @BenA for the fix. That works like a charm. +1 for the detailed explanation. That is very helpful indeed.

Comment: Tx @glibdud for the top question.

Comment: @Vishi I'm glad it helped, please do not forget to mark this as an answer if it solved your problem.